# Get queryset of foreignkey

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys

I need to obtain a queryset of a foreignkey but I haven't been able to figured out how.

I have the following model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='contact_set')
    referenced = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='contacted_by_set')
```

Then, for the current user I need a queryset that retrieves the referenced Users. The following returns Contact objects, I need User objects:

```
print request.user.contact_set.all()
```

Also, it needs to be a queryset because it will be used by a ModelMultipleChoiceField.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(contacted_by_set__owner=request.user)
```

should do it

Comment: +1 good call. That's definitely a better solution. I had a brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

Oji is correct with the syntax, but I would point out that this is actually a ManyToMany relationship. If you've shown the complete Contact definition, and there aren't any other tables, you could miss out the entire table and just define the relationship directly on CustomUser:

```
contacts = ManyToManyField('self', related_name='referenced_users')
```

Or, if you do have other fields on Contact, you can add `through='Contact'` on that ManyToManyField.

In either case, the query then becomes:

```
request.user.referenced_users.all()
```